# double loop in mysql with a complex update

Tags: mysql, loops

Hello brilliant minds of stack overflow,

Today I spent 4 hours trying to make an update command that would prevent me from having to fill a table with 150 lines, 3 columns each.

to achieve this I created the following update command:

```
UPDATE storage SET Quantity =
 (SELECT SUM(delivery_data.Quantity) FROM delivery_data, delivery, product 
 WHERE delivery_data.ID_Delivery = delivery.ID AND delivery.ID_Store = storage.ID_Store AND
 storage.ID_Store = 5 AND delivery_data.ID_Product = product.ID AND product.ID = 1)
 - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(purchase.Quantity) FROM purchase, sale, employee, product
 WHERE purchase.ID_Sale = sale.ID AND sale.ID_employee = employee.NIF
 AND employee.ID_Store = storage.ID_Store AND storage.ID_Store = 5
 AND purchase.ID_Product = product.ID AND product.ID = 1), 0) WHERE storage.ID_Store = 5
 AND storage.ID_Product = 1;
```

^ sorry for the unattractive code but its a really long update command and I didn't really know the best way to put it.

Anyhow, here is what is happening there if you think it is relevant:
I have a ton of tables, that create the setup of a company with deliveries and purchases (the deliveries are products bought by the company, the purchases are products bought by the clients) and I want to store how much of each product each store has in stock (the company has several stores), by calculating how much of that product has been delivered to the store, minus how much that store sold.

The command above works fine, however as you can probably tell it works only for store 5 and product 1, and to have it work for all 5 stores and 30 products, I would have to copy and paste it 150 times and change the values.

(Even though doing that would most likely be faster than trying to find how to to make a double loop in MySQL, overall its probably best if I learn this kind of thing.)

So yeah, to work around this issue I wrote a double loop from scraps of loops I found online, since I don't really fully know how they work. This is the code that gives me trouble:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE update_storage()

        BEGIN
            DECLARE x INT Default 1;
            DECLARE y INT Default 1;
            store: LOOP

                product: LOOP

                UPDATE storage SET Quantity = (SELECT DISTINCT delivery_data.Quantity FROM delivery_data, delivery, product WHERE delivery_data.ID_Delivery = delivery.ID AND delivery.ID_Store = storage.ID_Store AND storage.ID_Store = 5 AND delivery_data.ID_Product = product.ID AND product.ID = 1) - IFNULL((SELECT DISTINCT purchase.Quantity FROM purchase, venda, employee, product WHERE purchase.ID_Venda = venda.ID AND venda.ID_employee = employee.NIF AND employee.ID_Store = storage.ID_Store AND storage.ID_Store = 5 AND purchase.ID_Product = product.ID AND product.ID = 1), 0) WHERE storage.ID_Store = 5 AND storage.ID_Product = 1;

                SET y = y + 1;
                IF y = 31 THEN
                    LEAVE product;
                END IF;
                ITERATE product;
            END LOOP product;

            SET x = x + 1;
            IF x = 6 THEN
                LEAVE store;
            END IF;
            ITERATE store;
        END LOOP store;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

From what I tested, it seems to work for the 30 products on store 1, and then it gets stuck and I have to restart the MySQL console. if I change the X value to be default of 2, 3, etc it works, and that way I would only have to run 1 loop 5 times by hand, but like I said before, it would be more educating to find out how to do a double loop.

**TL;DR** What is making my double loop above stop working after the first run of the y variable? am I a total idiot? are double loops impossible in mysql? help is appreciated.

Comment: The usage of DISTINCT in the subqueries seems very odd to me.  For a given `(ID_Store,ID_Product)`, it seems like there would be more than one delivery. And given what looks like a one-to-many relationship between `delivery` and `delivery_data`,,, getting a list of DISTINCT values doesn't seem right. I know the question was about looping within a loop, but I'm stuck on the UPDATE statement that looks wrong.

Comment: @spencer7593 oh yeah you're right. honestly there is so much stuff inside that update command it's hard for me to know what I'm even doing :P

Comment: @spencer7593 fixed it, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I figured it out: I wasn't reseting the "y" variable so it always started at 31 after the first store. In case anyone looks at this looking for how to do a double loop, here is the general syntax:

```
    DELIMITER $$ --basically means what character(s) are used to finalize a command, which is ; by default
    CREATE PROCEDURE whateveryouwanttonamethis()

        BEGIN
            DECLARE x INT Default 1;
            DECLARE y INT;
            LOOP1: LOOP
                SET y = 1;
                LOOP2: LOOP

                    --What you whish to do with the loop, using X and Y as if they were fields of a table containing values

                    SET y = y + 1;
                    IF y = 999 THEN --replace 999 with the amount of times you want the inner loop to run for
                        LEAVE LOOP2;
                    END IF;
                ITERATE LOOP2;
                END LOOP LOOP2;

            SET x = x + 1;
            IF x = 999 THEN --replace 999 with the amount of times you want the outter loop to run for
                LEAVE LOOP1;
            END IF;
            ITERATE LOOP1;
        END LOOP LOOP1;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```